# Reading each line from text file

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, file-read

I have a script which reads each line from text file. but somehow it prints all at once. I want to run one line end and run next. here is the code.

```
f = open('textfile.txt', 'r')
    file= f.read()   
    for x in file:
        print(x, file.strip())
        comSerialPort.write(x.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `readlines` instead of `read`

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
        # do stuff with each line
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `with` statement and then iterate lines.

**Ex:**

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(line)
        comSerialPort.write(line.strip().encode('utf-8'))
```

**Note:** `read()` reads the entire content of the file.

Comment: that textfile.txt has a combination of letters that supposed to run in terminal and output each one result before running second combination. but the program is displaying one at a time without executing them.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand

Comment: so the textfile.txt has combination of letters like, AA, BB,CC,DD,EE,FF,GG,HH,II etc. when i run the file, it supposed to run each combinations one at a time executing it before running another combination. for example if it runs AA it need to display its output before running BB AND so on